Are there any other quests that have hidden "Can't continue when other quest is undone" sections?
I need to talk to Chrisseray to finish "Treacherous Light of the Depths", but her response to Punched Tape is:

Punched Tape? Now? The Central Laboratory blew up again! Sorry, but before that's cleared up, I don't have any time to worry about that stuff...

So I can't complete Treacherous Light until I finish "Fontaine Research Institute, Stagnating in the Rubble".
Are there any other unstated-in-the-Quests-Menu blockers like that? Because "Treacherous Light of the Depths" doesn't have the "Complete other quests to continue" red text.
